# Access field values of an instance in AllenNLP

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, allennlp

I´m using AllenNLP for a combined classifier (one of its task is NER tagging), and while designing some tests, I've come across this doubt: how do I access the values of the different fields of my AllenNLP instance? I want to compared them with the values introduced, to make sure nothing got lost in the preprocessing.

I managed to get to the text field of the instance using `instance.__getitem__("text")`, but I dont know how to get the value from there, or if there is anything quicker directly from the Instance class.

What I'm trying to do is something like `assert instance.getValueFromField("text) == training_dataset["text"][0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that `instance.__getitem__("text")` will let you access the field named "text", but you shouldn't use this method directly. Instead, just do `instance["text"]`.

Either way, this gives you a [`TextField`](https://github.com/allenai/allennlp/blob/ed322ebaf136955b8f9f060d8fc49a6c252a0bba/allennlp/data/fields/text_field.py#L29), with which you can inspect the tokens used to construct this field by looking at `instance["text"].tokens`.